# View account and contact details

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-developer

I've added a new field named Total to Account:

[image]

How to view the `Total` field and the contacts associated with an account?

Searching for "Account":

[image]

does not yield the account page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot is from setup, where you modify system's metadata.
Click the 3x3 grid icon and type Accounts there (or pick app like Sales), you'll go back to normal SF.

To see the field you might have to add it to account page layout. Or modify a listview, or make a report...

That's not really programming related, for pure admin questions you might be better off in dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/